# Bootstrap navigation anchor goes further than expected and then snaps back, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

So recently I have implemented smooth scroll given by CSS-Tricks, and a solution to closing the navigation bar when an option has been clicked. The problem is, that without the bootstrap script for closing the navigation, the scroll works perfect and stops at the anchors accurately.

However, as soon as I add the code for the automatic bootstrap navigation closing, when I then proceed to click on the link, it goes down to the desired anchor, misses it, continues and then suddenly shoots back to the anchor.

What could be the problem?

I hope someone will be able to help me. I have attached the relevant pieces of code below.

Smooth Scroll provided by CSS Tricks:

```
<script>
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
      &&
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ){
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

JavaScript code to close the bootstrap 3.x navigation:

```
<script>
  $('.navbar-collapse a').click(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
</script>
```

My HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Navigation logo and dropdown icon -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="logo">LOGO</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Options -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav-appearance">
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li id="main-nav"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

not 100% certain but it looks like the scroll script triggers and calculates the position in the document to scroll to and animates that over time provided.

Meanwhile your nav gets collapsed and removed from the document flow, meaning the calculation of position is now off so when the animation completes it has overshot desired position.

The scroll script then calls a callback function which gives focus to the target element, but as it is off the page giving focus causes it to snap back up the page so the focussed element is visible.

If you can call the scroll script after the bootstrap collapse script this should resolve the issue.